# MySQL - capture the changes on insertion

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL table `myTable` with 4 columns `id`,`name`,`version` and `date`. Everyday I get the data and this data changes only when they install new version of our products.

I would like to analyze the change in `version` numbers over time, to analyze when and how many customers are installing this new version.

For example,

`INSERT INTO MYtABLE (ID,NAME,VERSION,DATE) VALUES (1, 'ABC','1.0','07/21/2016');
INSERT INTO MYtABLE (ID,NAME,VERSION,DATE) VALUES (1, 'ABC','1.0','07/22/2016');
INSERT INTO MYtABLE (ID,NAME,VERSION,DATE) VALUES (1, 'ABC','1.1','07/23/2016');`

In this case, because of change in version from `1.0 to 1.1` I would like to capture the `name, id, date` of `07/23/2016`.

Here is my question:
How do i implement this in MySQL?

1. to implement Change Data Capture? I'm new to this and I couldn't find any tutorials as well.
2. I can think of Creating a `trigger` which captures this change. But it involves performance overhead.
3. Or a `SELECT` will work here?

Any better solns?

I can bear the performance! So upon insert, how do we compare the values to capture this change? Or How do I track these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is the best solution here.
There is another solution that you can schedule a script that run on every minutes or every 5 minutes and capture the data change.